# How to random order a user list with get_users

Tags: wordpress, random

I actually have a "users" page ordered by `post_count`.
I'm wondering if is possible to order the list randomly. I know that the `get_users`function just allows ordering by `'ID', 'login', 'nicename', 'email', 'url', 'registered', 'display_name', 'post_count', 'include',`or`'meta_value'`

For `get_posts`, if I remember well, there is a `rand` option to achieve this.

Here's the code of my template:

```html
<?php

/*
Template Name: Display Contributors and Authors
*/

    $args = array(
         'role'    => 'contributor',
         'orderby' => 'post_count',
         'order'   => 'DESC'
    );
 
    // only return users with published posts
 $args['has_published_posts'] = true;
    // run the WP_Query
 $contributors = get_users( $args );

    ?>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use following code to register order by rand:

```
add_action( 'pre_user_query', 'my_random_user_query' );

function my_random_user_query( $class ) {
    if( 'rand' == $class->query_vars['orderby'] )
        $class->query_orderby = str_replace( 'user_login', 'RAND()', $class->query_orderby );

    return $class;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
$args = array(
     'role'    => 'contributor',
     'orderby' => 'rand',
     'order'   => 'DESC'
);
```

[Source](http://www.codecheese.com/2014/05/order-wordpress-users-random/)

Comment: Thank you so much @madforstrength.
Worked perfectly.